# Showing that the mapping $a\in M, a^3=1,x\mapsto ax^2a^2$ is an automorphism of $M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

I am confused I have noticed. Perhaps you can clear up my confusion, which I can't pinpoint the origin of.

> Let $M$ be a monoid and $a\in M$ such that $a^3=1$, show that the mapping $x\mapsto ax^2a^2$ is an automorphism of $M$

So I know an automorphism to be a self-isomorphism(here $f:M\to M$), that seems alright. I know an isomorphism to be a bijective homomorphism, fair enough. So let's find if we have a homomorphism from above.

A homomorphic map must satisfy $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$:

$$f(x)f(y)=ax^2a^2ay^2a^2=ax^2a^3y^2a^2=ax^2y^2a^2=f(xy)$$
Happy days, we have the homomorphic property, and we are mapping from $f:M\to M$ so it is an endomorphism(so far).

What about bijection though to upgrade this endomorphism to an automorphism(so to speak), and we must satisfy $f(1_M)=1_M$ for an isomorphism.

---

Here is where my confusion comes in, $1_M$ I believe is the identity element of $M$, okay, let's find the identity element, we just take the binary operation $x\cdot 1_M = 1_M \cdot x = x$. Now I realise I don't know what my binary operation is. My function takes a single element?

Perhaps I need not show $f(1_M)=1_M$ or perhaps I truly am just confused, any ideas?

---

**Cohn - Classic Algebra - Chapter 3.1 - Monoids - Exercise 11$^*$ - Page 43**

*$*$I had a mistake in transcribing the exercise, and hence no fault of Cohn - $x \mapsto axa^2$ - Apologies!*

Comment: Offtopic: It is 2:34AM perhaps that is the true problem.

Comment: Showing that $f(1_M)=1_M$ is not very difficult. The most important thing you have left to show is that $f$ is bijective, i.e. surjective (sometimes called onto) and injective ("one-to-one").

Comment: I am confused about what your question is.  You began by specifying $a^3=1$.  Is that not a good way to "find the identity element" as you put it?  And you say you do not know what your binary operation is.  Neither do I, if it is not just the monoid multiplication.

Comment: Actually $f(xy) = a(xy)^2 a^2 = a (xyxy) a^2$, which need *not* be the same as $a (x^2 y^2) a^2 = f(x)f(y)$.  (Is $M$ assumed to be a *commutative* monoid?)

Comment: @mathmandan Ahhh yes, valid point, it isn't specified. In fact everything I know is in the shaded area of the post.

Comment: @Arthur What is $1_M$, or how do I find it here?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty That is a good way to find it, I missed the monoid multiplication(despite using it to prove homomorphism) since I am still having trouble with the 'abstract' part of abstract-algebra, e.g. breaking what I have always known apart($\Bbb R$). I suppose I must have $(M,\times)$ as my monoid

Comment: As stated, the problem statement is wrong. It has already been noted that $M$ needs to be *commutative*. Moreover, $f$ may fail to be onto: Let $(M,\cdot)=(\mathbb N_0,+)$ and $a=0$. Then $f(x)$ is even for all $x$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That is definitely a shame. Thank you!

I will amend that this is Cohn - Classic Algebra - Chapter 3.1 - Monoids - Exercise 11 - Page 43

Comment: It might help to read what Cohn (3rd edition, 2000) actually writes, which is to consider $x\mapsto axa^2$.

Comment: The element $1_M$ is guaranteed to exist by the definition of a monoid. That is how you "get" to it.

Comment: @Did Apologies you are totally right. This is entirely my mistake. I'll add to the reference(as to not slander it)

Comment: No worries. At the end of the day, this helped you to see why $x\mapsto ax^2a^2$ is *not* a morphism, in general, when the monoid is not abelian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if $M$ is a *group* (not just a monoid), and even if $M$ is *commutative* (not specified), the conclusion is false.  Let $M = \mathbb{C}^*$, the group of nonzero complex numbers under multiplication, and let $a = e^{2\pi i / 3}$, so that $a^3 = e^{2\pi i} = 1$.  Now define $f: M \to M$ by $f(x) = ax^2 a^2$.

Then $f$ is indeed a (group) homomorphism, but it is not one-to-one:
$$
f(-1) = a (-1)^2 a^2 = a(1) a^2 = a^3 = 1,
$$
and
$$
f(1) = a(1)^2 a^2 = a^3 = 1.
$$

Actually for this example we could restrict to just the circle group, or indeed even the cyclic group of order $6$.